# Higher Order Function return null

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, higher-order-functions

[image]

I'm going to MenuFragment from MainActivty and calling RecyclerViewAdapter inside in MenuFragment class to set my data to show . then I want to set the callback in my Adapter using higher order function (Kotlin language) to send the data to MainActivity to change something in BottomNavigationView UI.

MainActivty class:

```
val callbackFromAdapter=RecyclerAdapterInside(null,null,this,::callbackAdapterInside)

    private fun callbackAdapterInside(OrderList:MutableList<OrderLive>)
    {
        var totalSum=0

        for(elements in OrderList)
        {
            totalSum+=elements.getcount()

        }
        Log.d("oncell", "$totalSum")
        if(totalSum>0)
        {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                badge_current_order.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                badge_current_order.setText(totalSum)
            }
        }

        else
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                badge_current_order.setText(0)
                badge_current_order.visibility=View.GONE
            }
    }
```

RecyclerAdapterInside class:

```
class RecyclerAdapterInside(
    PlaceId:String?=null, var myReceivedData: List<ItemClass>?=null, val context:Context,
    val CurrentCartUpdateCallback: ((OrderList: MutableList<OrderLive>) -> Unit?)? = null):RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

...

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            if(CurrentCartUpdateCallback!=null) { //never pass this condition
                CurrentCartUpdateCallback!!(myOrderLive)
                Log.d("tagtest", "Callback is called ")
            }
        }
    }
```

I said I'm using RecyclerAdapterInside in my MenuFragment class to set data.

```
       recyclerview.adapter=RecyclerAdapterInside(
            id,
            result,
            this@MenuFragment.requireContext(),
            null
        )
```

for this reason I should create the type of null for CurrentCartUpdateCallback variable. Because I never use this callback in MenuFragmentClass and I always pass null when I don't need callback in this class. so I just use it in MainActivity class.

The problem is callbackAdapterInside is never called and CurrentCartUpdateCallback is always null in:

```
if(CurrentCartUpdateCallback!=null)
```

I don't use higher order function much. Do I have to use this callback in order of class numbers
Adapter->3->2->1 or can I use callback directly from the adapter class to the Main activity class ?

Comment: Your RecyclerAdapterInside constructor has four params, and the fourth is CurrentCartUpdateCallback, so when you create an instance in your MenuFragment, you are using the value null, so is normal don´t continue the if condition

Comment: @ManuelMato Tnx. See the instance of adapter in MainActivity class. I want to use callback result In MainActivity class not MenuFragment Class. So I guess pass the null is reasonable in MenuFtagment.

Comment: I think that handle a recycler view is very very easy but in this flow is very difficult so i think is necessary to rethink the approach... For example, if you activity contains a fragment named MenuFragment, and this fragment contains a recycler view, the MenuFragment must receive the callback and then you need to communicate the fragment with the activity, for example activity.doSomething or sharing a ViewModel or Presenter... and the RecyclerView only needs to receive by constructor a lambda to received the holder click and the data to show if the data is inmutable for example

Comment: @ManuelMato Yes You are right. But I don't know MVVM architecture much. All fragment are a part of MainActivity. I understand what you said. the thing I want to do is when sum of Items of recyclerView is more that 0, I conclude there is a order list in my active shopping cart. I want to add the counter of my item orders to bottomNavigationView as a badge counter. I wanted to do this by callback method. when callback is called UI counter in bottomNavigationView is updated. I might think about using shared preference to get the result . saving counter of active order in shared preference...

Comment: Yes, you right, it is difficult to do this if your are rookie in android, it is normal :) so step by step, i can´t give you an easy approach to add to your code, sorry